# Показать/скрыть лишние товары

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Сделал контейнер с фиксированной высотой и `overflow: hidden` что бы при загрузке страницы показывались только те товары которые помещаются по высоте, а при нажатии на кнопку все остальные. Но при изменении ширины экрана, высота карточек тоже меняется и нижние частично выходят за границу. Можно ли сделать на css, что бы нижние карточки не выходили за нее? На ум приходит только зафиксировать высоту карточек, но это тоже не очень удобно.

```
    <div class="goods ">
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css:

```
.shop .goods {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 2340px;
}
```

css при нажатии на кнопку:

```
.goods.active {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это очень не оптимальное решение, поскольку вы не знаете с какого устройства прийдет смотреть вашу верстку пользователь. Никогда не фиксируйте `height`, если когда-то в ваших задачах и понадобиться, то используйте - `max-height:`
Что до решения, можете сделать так.

```css
.shop .goods:nth-of-type(n +5) {
    display: none;
}
.goods.active  .good__item{
   display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="goods ">
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="good__item flex">
                    <div class="good__item_thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/mellowlife/img/goods_thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__title">
                        <a href="#">Product longest name ever testing here please stay calm</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goods__item_buy flex">
                        <span class="goods__cost">75</span>
                        <span class="add__to_cart">add to cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Тоесть визуальное отображение курируеться от класса оббертки. (наличие/отсуцтвие у него доп класса)

Comment: Спасибо! Простое решение, но я почему-то не додумался до этого.